# How to store rabbitmq RABBITMQ_MNESIA_DIR on remote disk

Tags: amazon-web-services, server, rabbitmq, queue, storage

We have two ec2 servers. One has the **rabbitmq** on it. Second one is a new one for storage purposes. Both of these are `Amazon Linux 2`.

On the second one we just purchased `/dev/nvme1n1     70G  104M   70G   1% /data`
Where we would love to push our rabbitmq queues and data. Basically we would like to `RABBITMQ_MNESIA_DIR` setup on the first rabbitmq server to be directly connecting and saving queues in `/data` remote mentioned.

Currently that is `/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia` and our config file for rabbitmq is just default `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf`

I wonder if somebody has been doing this before, or can point us in the right direction on how to set `RABBITMQ_MNESIA_DIR` to be directly connecting to remote ec2 and store and work with queues from there. Thank you

Comment: This is really not something that you want to do, because you'll be introducing network lags into the core operation of RabbitMQ. Why not just add 70G to your primary broker node? Or move the broker?

Comment: Hmm thank you so much for saying @Parsifal . We will definitely rethink it, thank you for the information :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the day @Parsifal was right.
We ended up making one instance bigger and changed `RABBITMQ_MNESIA_DIR`

This was bit tricky, because after restarting `service rabbitmq-server restart`
First off was needed to make sure we had current right to the `/data/mnesia` we mounted, I managed it with `chmod 755 -R /data` though read/write should be sufficient based on docs.

Then we were looking for why it always produces the error like this `"broker forced connection closure with reason 'shutdown'"` &  `Error on AMQP connection` so it was after the start.

So I figured and checked the ownership of the current `mnesia` dir and the new one. And turned out the user and group was `root root` compared to original one.
Switched it to `drwxr-xr-x 4 rabbitmq rabbitmq 97 Dec 16 14:57 mnesia` and this started working.
Maybe it will save you some headaches, I didn't realize there was a different user group for rabbitmq, since I didn't create it.

Only thing to add, is once you are shifting the current working mnesia you might consider copying the directory to the new one since there is a lot of stuff that was currently being used and ran from. I tried it without it and even the password to admin didn't work :D